# Have Python's 'configparser' to treat lines under an ini section as (raw) lines?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, configuration-files, ini, configparser

Trying to make *configparser* treat lines under a section as raw text, and returning each line as *items*:

Example config/ini file:

```
[db]
sqlite:///testing.db
mysql:///user:pass@host/database
```

The code i've currently got:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read( self.configFile )
print config.items('db')
```

However, this will return the lines as:

```
[('sqlite', '///testing.db'), ('mysql', '///user:pass@host/database')]
```

Any way it could be done without having to concatenate the list items returned?

Comment: That's not valid in the `.ini` file format. Where are you getting the file you're trying to read?

Comment: @kindall I'm not sure what you mean. The ini/cfg file is an actual file stored on my harddrive. The file is being read fine by *configparser* , i'm just wondering if *configparser* could be made to ignore the name+value format under the specified section. That's why *allow_no_value=True* is added.

(*self.configFile* is just a filename)

Comment: @felipsmartins bah! I guess i had to move onto Python 3 eventually. Thanks!

Comment: @DhP if it still requires Python 2.x there is a port of Python 3 ConfigParser for Python 2.x: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser